# Raster Plotting with Grayscale: both 0 and 1 are plotted in white

Tags: r, plot

I have the following example code:

```
library(raster)
library(SpaDES)

m = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0,
         0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
         0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),nrow=4,
         ncol=10, byrow=TRUE )
r <- raster(m)
Plot(r, cols = grey.colors(10, start=0, end=1), title = "4x10 Raster")
```

This should produce a 4x10 Raster, where each `0` represents a black square, a `1` a white square and the other numbers gray squares. Unfortunately, both one and zero (as well as the background) are white. How can I get the zeros to appear as a black square?

[Raster with white instead of black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYUKP.png)

Edit: I am using the R package "SpaDES" for ecological applications, `Plot` is a function from that package. It is very important that the raster squares are plotted as squares no matter the shape of the plot viewer or the size of the raster, since it represents a rastered map.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think it has something to do with zero.color = NULL: "zero.color 
Character string indicating the color for zero values, when zero is the minimum value, otherwise, zero is treated as any other color. Default transparent."

Comment: For some reason, the following works: `Plot(r, cols = grey.colors(10, start=0, end=1), title = "4x10 Raster", na.color = "black")`
I don't understand why, since `na.color` is supposed to be "Character string indicating the color for `NA` values. Default transparent." Also, I would prefer not to set it as "black" but to just include it as a normal number in the grey.colors gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way to solve my problem while still using the `Plot` function of the `SpaDES` package instead of `plot` seems to be the following:

```
library(raster)
library(SpaDES)

m = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0,
         0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
         0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),nrow=4,
       ncol=10, byrow=TRUE )
r <- raster(m)

Plot(r, cols = grey.colors(10, start=0, end=1), title = "4x10 Raster", na.color = "black")
```

[raster plot with zeros plotted in black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gJkE.png)

I still don't understand why changing options for `zero.color` does not work. Here are the definitions from the `Plot` function from `SpaDES`:

> ```
> na.color    Character string indicating the color for NA values. Default transparent.
> zero.color  Character string indicating the color for zero values, when zero is the minimum value, otherwise, zero is treated as any other color. Default transparent.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I did this:

```
plot(r, col = grey.colors(10, start=0, end=1), main = "4x10 Raster")
```

and got this:

[image]

Changed `Plot` to `plot`, `cols` to `col`, and `title` to `main`.

Comment: This solves the black / white issue but doesn't really work for me. In my case, I have a raster map, and the squares really need to remain squares. Turns out that "Plot" is a {SpaDES} function, which I would like to use because it goes well with the rest of my program. I will edit my post accordingly. Thanks, though,

Comment: Sure thing @Apatura, hopefully I can Answer that question as well, you might want to ask another question instead of editing this one, since this answer might help other people.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot (thanks!!!) because it showed me that the issue is within the `Plot` function. I did not even notice that this was a function from a specialized package. But I am not sure how it can help others because with the `plot` function my problem does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

From @Derek Corcoran's correction. I add some code to preserve the aspect ratio of the raster.

```
library(raster)
library(SpaDES)
m = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0,
             0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
             0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5),nrow=4,
           ncol=10, byrow=TRUE )
r <- raster(m)
#the aspect ratio should be modified to "0.4". 
plot(r,asp=0.4,col = grey.colors(10, start=0, end=1))
#Because it is the relation beetween columns and rows.
```

[image]